# How do I write HTML in my post without it getting "translated"?

Tags: discussion, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

How do I write HTML in my post without it getting "translated"?

I would like to be able to show you guys my raw code. Hope you can help me out with this noobish problem.

**EDIT:**

```
<div>
  <p>Here is some markup</p>
  <p>I typed it out, highlighted it, and clicked the code button.
  You know the one with the curly braces { }
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what does translated mean and please do show the relevant part of your code

Answer (score 2):

Either surround your code with backticks (for inline code) or indent each of your lines of code by at least 4 spaces. Or hit the code format button. It looks like a set of braces.
So, it'd look like this:

SpaceSpaceSpaceSpace `<html>`

SpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpace `<head> //will look correctly indented`

SpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpace  `//lots of html`

SpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpace `</head>`

SpaceSpaceSpaceSpace `</html>`

Ok, maybe that's overkill.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: @Ibu pardon me if this sounds rude, but... what? This is a direct answer to his question. In no way should it be a comment. If this should be a comment, the question isn't possible to answer, and thus shouldn't be on here (which may indeed be the case)

Comment: @Ibu, why? It's an answer to the guy's question surely?

Comment: @lbu Just to pile on, this is most certainly an answer to the question. (I flag *lots* of "Not an Answer" posts, and I wouldn't dream of flagging this one)

Comment: You could also wrap it in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: @Servy in response to your edit comment - obviously your IDE just doesn't have enough dimensions :)

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Where's the link to Chrome 3D?  I'm totally in.  (God I hope I don't need to start developing 3D websites.  2D is bad enough.)

Comment: @Servy well, first you gotta go buy a 3D monitor and subscribe to SO-3D

Comment: @Servy but on a serious-er note, I found out yesterday that webkit actually supports css3 3D transformations. Cool, huh?

Comment: @Ibu what are you talking about?

Comment: Ibu thinks this is an actual Stack Overflow question and you're trying to tell him how to format code, so he thinks it should be a comment.

Comment: Nope, @Servy, `<pre>` is just to preserve whitespace. It does not encode HTML entities. So one would need to type `<pre>&lt;html&gt;...&lt;/html&gt;</pre>` then. Markdown code blocks are much easier.

Answer (score 0):

highlight your code, and press `control+k`

Comment: assuming you have a control key, if not, press the apple button or whatever it is

Comment: No sense in commenting on your post to add content if you can edit it :)